# How to override jquery autocomplete's menuitem?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery's autocomplete:

Next to label and value, I would like to display a picture. I am sending the necessary data as json to the java script. But I am not sure how to override the auto-generated menu-item to add an `<img src=pic_url />` to it.

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/search/" + request.term,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.username, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.id,
                                pic_url: item.pic_url
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('e', arguments);
                    }
                });
            ...
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the _renderItem method:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({..}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            var html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><img src="' + item.picture + '" /><span>' + item.label + '</span></div></a>';
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append(html)
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to start investigating the `._renderItem` method of Autocomplete. It gives you much more flexibility for the widget.

[Here is a nice complex use of the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666674/jquery-autocomplete-with-renderitem-and-catagories)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Autocomplete - Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

You can alter the template within the _renderItem method... see the section at the bottom of the script tags in the example.